# Splitting a list into single list amounts

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to split a list in python to single amounts but I can't seem to get it to work and I can't find any questions on stackoverflow which try to achieve this

At the moment, I've got code which is producing id's but I need those id's separate

`['325', '323', '324', '322']`

I want to split these so they go into

```
['323']
['324']
['322']
```

What would be the best way to do this?

The list has different amounts and some of them only have one id

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I've mainly been looking at str.split, but that seems to just group it into another [' '], I also looked at splitting it after the comma but again it just keeps it in the same list

Comment: `[[i] for i in list_]`

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want? It seems unlikely you'd need a list of lists with one element each.

Comment: @sahasrara62 Please write it up as an answer.

Comment: @AdamSmith I think so, I'm using an api to export files but I need to run a url with each id in it, the id's are produced in different lists with different lengths so I just need them separate, I'm trying to automate it as much as possible

Comment: @KarlKnechtel added

Answer (score 1):

since you want each element of the list in a separate/individual  list, then you have to iterate through the original list and add an element in a empty list and append that new list to the resultant list.

```
 main_list = ['325', '323', '324', '322']
 final_solution = []
 for element in main_list:
       tmp = [element]
       final_solution.append(tmp)
 print(final_solution)

 # output -> [['325'], ['323'], ['324'], ['322']]`
```

or, by using `list comprehension`

```
final_solution = [[element] for element in main_list]
print(final_solution)

# output -> [['325'], ['323'], ['324'], ['322']]`
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple one-liner that turns each item in the list to an array containing the item:

```py
list(map(lambda x : [x], arr))
```

so if you have `arr = [1,2,3]` :

```
>>> a = list(map(lambda x : [x], arr))
>>> print(a)
[[1], [2], [3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ['325', '323', ['324', '327'], '345', '322']
new_list = []
for i in my_list:
     if type(i) == str:
         new_list.append([i])
     else:
          for j in i:
              new_list.append([j])
```

`new_list = [['325'], ['323'], ['324'], ['327'], ['345'], ['322']]`.